# Which is the preferred language to implement machine learning algorithms?

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, python-3.x, machine-learning

Through a quick online exploration I came across Python, R, C/C++ and even Java, JavaScript being used to implement machine learning algorithms.

Can someone pls comment on which is the most preferred language and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, **Python** is the goto language for Machine Learning / Deep learning.

It is not only a very famous and capable language, but it's on the rise too. In the recent years, there have been developed many great frameworks and libraries for Machine learning in Python, including the release of TensorFlow.

Another example, the very well-known new coursera course from Andrew Ng "Deep learning" is using Python and Jupiter notebooks for the classes.

Answer (score -1):

Except of the mentioned languages, you should check Prolog. It is a dedicated language for AI. It is used primarily in academic research and has great capabilities.